# PostgreSQL Partition and Unique Conflict

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-partitioning

I am attempting to set up a database with partitions, however I am running into an error when creating the activity table. The 3 Table CREATEs (without the actual data) are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE collection (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);


CREATE TABLE asset (
    id SERIAL,
    collection_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_collection
        FOREIGN KEY(collection_id)
            REFERENCES collection(id),
    CONSTRAINT asset_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id, collection_id)
)PARTITION BY LIST(collection_id);


CREATE TABLE activity(
    id SERIAL,
    collection_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_collection
        FOREIGN KEY(collection_id)
            REFERENCES collection(id),
    CONSTRAINT activity_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id, collection_id),
    asset_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_asset
        FOREIGN KEY(asset_id)
            REFERENCES asset(id)
) PARTITION BY LIST(collection_id);

ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "asset"
SQL state: 42830
```

My understanding of the error is that foreign keys must be unique. Because I must add collection_id as a primary key to partition item, I cannot also designate id as unique. When I attempt to make id unique, this is what happens:

```
ALTER TABLE asset
    ADD CONSTRAINT u_id UNIQUE (id);

ERROR:  unique constraint on partitioned table must include all partitioning columns
DETAIL:  UNIQUE constraint on table "asset" lacks column "collection_id" which is part of the partition key.
SQL state: 0A000
```

Even if I successfully add the UNIQUE constraint on id and collection_id, it continues to throw me SQL state: 42830. Do I have to restructure my data or is there a better way to go about this that I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be enough to merge the foreign keys on `asset` into one composite key, or does that violate some other constraint of your data?

```sql
CREATE TABLE activity(
    id SERIAL,
    collection_id INT,
    asset_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT activity_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id, collection_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_asset_collection
        FOREIGN KEY(asset_id, collection_id)
            REFERENCES asset(id, collection_id)
) PARTITION BY LIST(collection_id);
```

Comment: Brilliant! I don't know how I didn't think about just getting the collection_id from the asset table. Thank you!